# List of objects to partial view using Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, partial-views

I'm currently in the process of converting an application into Knockout.
Currently there are a number of views that within them will loop round a list of objects within the model to then pass to a partialview to render that object.

```
<div>
    foreach (var item in Model.ListData) {
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_ListPanel.cshtml", item);
            }
        }
</div>
```

In my knockout view model I have the same list of objects as an observable array. What would be the best way to pass each of them to the parital view and bind using knockout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) binding to iterate through the elements:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Children -->
    //your partial view
<!-- /ko -->
```

Inside the partial view bind to the properties of the object as appropriate.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I was originally looking to pass the children to the partial but may as well just scrap the partial. Cheers